# Validation Using service layer in mvc 4 to achieve server side and client side validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

Hi I have table employee with some fields

to validate fields I have created two layers

1. Service layer
2. Employee repository

Employee repository code is

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{

    public interface IEmployeeMainTableRepository
    {
        bool CreateEmployee(EMP_MAIN_TBL EmployeeToCreate);
        IEnumerable<EMP_MAIN_TBL> ListEmployees();
    }


    public class EmployeeRepository : MvcApplication2.Models.IEmployeeMainTableRepository
    {
        private EMPLOYEE_SYSTEMEntities _entities = new EMPLOYEE_SYSTEMEntities();


        public IEnumerable<EMP_MAIN_TBL> ListEmployees()
        {
            return _entities.EMP_MAIN_TBL.ToList();
        }


        public bool CreateEmployee(EMP_MAIN_TBL EmployeeToCreate)
        {
            try
            {
              // _entities.AddToEMP_MAIN_TBL(productToCreate);
                _entities.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }


    }
```

And service layer contains

```
    public interface IEmployeeService

    {
        bool CreateEmployee(EMP_MAIN_TBL EmployeeToCreate);
        System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<EMP_MAIN_TBL> ListEmployees();
    }

    public class EmployeeService : MvcApplication2.Models.IEmployeeService
    {


        private IValidationDictionary _validatonDictionary;
        private IEmployeeMainTableRepository _repository;

        public EmployeeService(IValidationDictionary validationDictionary, IEmployeeMainTableRepository repository)
        {
            _validatonDictionary = validationDictionary;
            _repository = repository;
        }



        protected bool ValidateEmployee(EMP_MAIN_TBL employeeToValidate)
        {
            if (employeeToValidate.EMP_NM == null)
                _validatonDictionary.AddError("EMP_NM", "Name is required.");
            if (employeeToValidate.PLCE_OF_BRTH == null)
                _validatonDictionary.AddError("PLCE_OF_BRTH", "Place of birth is required.");

            return _validatonDictionary.IsValid;
        }

        public IEnumerable<EMP_MAIN_TBL> ListEmployees()
        {
            return _repository.ListEmployees();
        }

        public bool CreateEmployee(EMP_MAIN_TBL EmployeeToCreate)
        {
            // Validation logic
            if (!ValidateEmployee(EmployeeToCreate))
                return false;

            // Database logic
            try
            {
                _repository.CreateEmployee(EmployeeToCreate);
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

and I have created two more classes to add validation messages

```
public interface IValidationDictionary
{
    void AddError(string key, string errorMessage);
    bool IsValid { get; }
}
```

And

```
public class ModelStateWrapper : IValidationDictionary
    {

        private ModelStateDictionary _modelState;

        public ModelStateWrapper(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
            _modelState = modelState;
        }

        #region IValidationDictionary Members

        public void AddError(string key, string errorMessage)
        {
            _modelState.AddModelError(key, errorMessage);
        }

        public bool IsValid
        {
            get { return _modelState.IsValid; }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

finally employee controllers contains below structure

```
  public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        private IEmployeeService _service;

        public EmployeeController()
        {
            _service = new EmployeeService(new ModelStateWrapper(this.ModelState), new EmployeeRepository());
        }

        public EmployeeController(IEmployeeService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }


        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_service.ListEmployees());
        }


        //
        // GET: /Product/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View(new EMP_MAIN_TBL());
        }

        //
        // POST: /Product/Create

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "EMP_ID")] EMP_MAIN_TBL employeeToCreate)
        {
            if (!_service.CreateEmployee(employeeToCreate))
                return View();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


    }
}
```

and my view looks like this

[image]

My question is above code working fine for server side validation

but how do I achieve validation on client side using above same code 
please

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already validating on the service side you could return the ModelStateDictionary instead of the bool, you could then check that it is valid on the client side.
But this won't help when it comes to checking that the whole service method has finished, so you could create a new type that returns say a bool and the ModelStateDictionary.

Another approach is to use Fault Exceptions. You can create your own fault exception that would get thrown when the model state is not valid. This Model State Fault could contain your ModelStateDictionary.

So from that you have three options.

1. Change the return type to the ModelStateDictionary.
2. Create a new return type to return a result and a ModelStateDictionary.
3. Use Fault Exceptions that occur when the Model State isn't valid.

Personally I would use the third approach, as you can then still use your original return type, and then just need to catch the Fault like you would an Exception. Here is an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/294609/Uing-FaultContract-to-throw-custom-error-informati) and also [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff650547.aspx)

Comment: Could you attach some code where do I return modelstatedictionary

Comment: my idea is i don't want to post form to server side for validation i want to get validations error on client side without using dataannotation and jquery