# How to achieve both client and server side validation using one set of rules in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing mvc project currently.
Right now I am using data annotation for validation. This is fine but when I used custom data annotation I mean custom validation, client side validation not working and it only fires when I post the form to server. But I have used dynamically creation controls in my application if I use custom validation attributes to dynamically created controls I have lost dynamically created controls. so how do I fire client side validation for custom attributes ..

Is there any way to right set of rules in one layer and it has to apply both server and client side?

Comment: Your `ValidationAttribute` needs to implement `IClientValidatable`. [Refer this example](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: Thank u Mr Stephen Muecke I have implemented same thing but this is two time process like we need to write both c# code and jquery can we use service layer to write validation rules and this layer has to apply both server and client side and please refer this link I have already posted and answer was not clear

Comment: Link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26776849/validation-using-service-layer-in-mvc-4-to-achieve-server-side-and-client-side-v

Comment: above link working for server side and not working on client side please post answer your help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to read the link I gave you in my first comment, but your other question does not have custom data annotations for validation so I don't really know what your trying to do or how your doing it.

Comment: sorry  in that link am not using dataannotations and jquery but its works same as dataannotaions could you cross check once please..right now Iam using same validation technique to apply client side validation please help me based on that link

Comment: Its not the same as data annotations. Read the link in my first comment!

Comment: Am planning to apply validaton based on service laye(based on link I have posted) because we can define validation rules in one layer and it is very easy to maintain application and we can have more control over on application please help

Comment: I have read and I understood perfectly too but my intension is to avoid writing too much of code

Comment: chat option not enabled for me because its showing some reputation stuff am new to stack overflow

Comment: There is nothing more to discuss. If you don't want to write the code to have client side validation, then don't!